# Where to get Azure search query logs to check a query?

Tags: content-search, azure-search

We are using Azure search to get the Sitecore items based on some filter conditions passed as predicate. This condition is not working with Azure Search in our dev environment. We have to check the search query logs so that we can verify the query formed based on the input predicate.

Where can we check the Sitecore search query logs on an Azure environment?

Answer (score 2):

The search logs are part of the actual log file in Sitecore Azure installation. You can access them in your webapp files.

You can access them by following the steps below.

1. Login to azure portal, go to your CM/CD when app
2. Go to Development Tools
3. Select App Service Editor (Preview)
4. This will Open the file explorer of your site
5. Go to `App_Data --> Logs --> "Your Instance Name Folder"` and you will see the log files with name `azure.log.date.time.txt`
6. Search this files for `AzureSearch Query` to get the actual query

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also would like to use Azure KUDU for these purposes. (Just commented one more way to see files in Azure) :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup.. they are logged to the search logs. If you have a rather standard setup, you will find them in Application Insights.

Another option is to (temporarily) enable `Application Logging (Filesystem)` in the "App Service logs" on the server where you perform the query. Set the level to Info to get the search log information. Once enabled, you can go to the "Log stream" and follow the logs live. As soon as you notice the search query log you can pause the logs to easily copy/paste the data you need.

For debugging purposes on a dev environment (where you probably have no traffic), I find the log stream the easiest solution.